# Scroll to very bottom of SwiftUI Scrollview when keyboard appears

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

In my SwiftUI project, I have the following layout

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        Text("some text that may change while editing the stuff below")
        TextField(...)
        TextField(...)
        Button(...)
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is that whenever the TextField gets focus, the ScrollView scrolls to the very bottom, i.e. the button is visible. I tried with a wrapped `UIScrollView` and also keyboardWillShow-notifications, but didn't find anything that worked on both, iOS 13 and 14.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this by using a `ScrollViewReader`, and if you don't want the `onTapGesture`, you can use `keyboardWillShow-notifications`

```
ScrollView {
    ScrollViewReader { value in
        VStack {
            Text("some text that may change while editing the stuff below").id(0)
            TextField(...)
                .id(1)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation() {
                        value.scrollTo(3, anchor: .top) //or if you want the button in the center use .center
                    }
                 }
            TextField(...).id(2)
            Button(...).id(3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great one! Just one addition, I needed to hold a boolean flag at `View` scope to check before scrolling and reset it at `onTapGesture` to avoid sequential and uncontrolled scrolling behaviour when `textField` is tapped many times

Comment: Wow I have been stuck on this issue for days now this is the best solution